# Custom Wordpress Search Result Page Displays 404

Tags: wordpress, search, url-rewriting

Custom Wordpress Search Result Page not working and redirects to 404.

Target Url: https://example.com/blog/search/?post_type=post&s=a

```
// CUSTOM BLOG POST SEARCH FORM

     function blog_search_form( $blog_form ) {
     $blog_form = '

     <form class="form-inline" id="search" action="'.home_url( "/blog/search/" ).'" method="get">
     <div class="form-group mx-sm-1 mb-2 w-100">
         <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="post" />
         <input class="form-control w-100" id="s" name="s" type="text" placeholder="Search blog" value="' . get_query_var('s') . '" required  />
     </div>
     <input id="searchsubmit" class="main-btn btn mb-2" type="submit" value="Search" />
     </form>';

     return $blog_form;
     }

     add_filter( 'get_search_form', 'blog_search_form' );
```

```
// CHANGE URL FUNCTION
/function wpb_change_search_url() {
        if ( is_search() && ! empty( $_GET['s'] ) ) {
            wp_redirect( home_url( "/blog/search/" ) . urlencode( get_query_var( 's' ) ) );
            exit();
        }
    }
    add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wpb_change_search_url' );
```